# I am using keras , but it is throwing a error with the helper libraries. No module names "lstm"

Tags: keras

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense,Activation,Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
import time,lstm
```

The error message is No module name "lstm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have already imported `LSTM` from `keras.layers`, so there's no reason to import `lstm` again. According to the [examples](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/), I don't see any instances of the (lower case) `lstm` import, just the `LSTM` from `keras.layers`.

Comment: basically i am using lstm to load the data using lstm.load_data. I tried your approach but it is still saying LSTM has no attribute load_data. Can you tell me a way to load the data

Comment: @varunchauhan is there a tutorial that you're following telling you to use that function? I'm not seeing it in the examples

Comment: yes, I  saw video of Siraj and tried the same code which is on stock prediction.

Comment: From the information you've given, I'm guessing you're following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftMq5ps503w&vl=en). If that's the case, the link in the description goes to a repository containing [this file](https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Predict-Stock-Prices-Easily-Demo/blob/master/lstm.py), which you'll need to download and put in the same directory as your code.